# Angular - Cannot read properties of undefined when subscribe to function

Tags: angular, typescript

on my angular app i have a error on browser debug:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties
> of undefined (reading 'fields')

Why I cannot access to fields property in this line?

```
this.pictureUrl = this.currentUser.version.fields.field[0].fieldValue.path;
```

this is my user model

```
export interface EzUser {
  mediaType: string;
  href: string;
  id: number;
  remoteID: string;
  contentType: ContentType;
  name: string;
  versions: ContentType;
  section: ContentType;
  mainLocation: ContentType;
  locations: ContentType;
  groups: ContentType;
  owner: ContentType;
  publishDate: Date;
  lastModificationDate: Date;
  mainLanguageCode: string;
  alwaysAvailable: boolean;
  version: Version;
  login: string;
  email: string;
  enabled: boolean;
  userGroups: ContentType;
  roles: ContentType;
}

export interface ContentType {
  mediaType: string;
  href: string;
}

export interface Version {
  mediaType: string;
  href: string;
  versionInfo: VersionInfo;
  fields: Fields;
  relations: Relations;
  thumbnail: Thumbnail;
}

export interface Fields {
  field: Field[];
}

export interface Field {
  id: number;
  fieldDefinitionIdentifier: string;
  languageCode: string;
  fieldTypeIdentifier: string;
  fieldValue: FieldValueClass;
}

export interface FieldValueClass {
  hasStoredLogin?: boolean;
  contentID?: number;
  login?: string;
  email?: string;
  passwordUpdatedAt?: number;
  enabled?: boolean;
  maxLogin?: number;
  plainPassword?: null;
  id?: string;
  path?: string;
  alternativeText?: string;
  fileName?: string;
  fileSize?: number;
  imageID?: string;
  uri?: string;
  inputURI?: null;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  additionalData?: any[];
  variations?: Variations;
}

export interface Variations {
  ezplatformAdminUIProfilePictureUserMenu: string;
  large: string;
  medium: string;
  reference: string;
  small: string;
  tiny: Href;
}

export interface Href {
  href: string;
}

export interface Relations {
  mediaType: string;
  href: string;
  relation: any[];
}

export interface Thumbnail {
  mediaType: string;
  resource: string;
  width: null;
  height: null;
  mimeType: string;
}

export interface VersionInfo {
  id: number;
  versionNo: number;
  status: string;
  modificationDate: Date;
  creator: ContentType;
  creationDate: Date;
  initialLanguageCode: string;
  languageCodes: string;
  versionTranslationInfo: VersionTranslationInfo;
  names: Names;
  content: ContentType;
}

export interface Names {
  value: Value[];
}

export interface Value {
  languageCode: string;
  text: string;
}

export interface VersionTranslationInfo {
  mediaType: string;
  language: Language[];
}

export interface Language {
  languageCode: string;
}
```

this is my data

```
{
    "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.User+json",
    "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/user/users/14",
    "_id": 14,
    "_remoteId": "1bb4fe25487f05527efa8bfd394cecc7",
    "ContentType": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.ContentType+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/types/4"
    },
    "name": "Administrator User",
    "Versions": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.VersionList+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/objects/14/versions"
    },
    "Section": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.Section+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/sections/2"
    },
    "MainLocation": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.Location+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/locations/1/5/13/15"
    },
    "Locations": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.LocationList+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/objects/14/locations"
    },
    "Groups": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.UserGroupRefList+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/user/users/14/groups"
    },
    "Owner": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.User+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/user/users/14"
    },
    "publishDate": "2002-10-06T16:13:50+00:00",
    "lastModificationDate": "2021-12-21T17:23:49+00:00",
    "mainLanguageCode": "eng-GB",
    "alwaysAvailable": true,
    "Version": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.Version+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/objects/14/versions/5",
        "VersionInfo": {
            "id": 517,
            "versionNo": 5,
            "status": "PUBLISHED",
            "modificationDate": "2021-12-21T17:23:49+00:00",
            "Creator": {
                "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.User+json",
                "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/user/users/14"
            },
            "creationDate": "2021-12-21T17:23:48+00:00",
            "initialLanguageCode": "eng-GB",
            "languageCodes": "eng-GB",
            "VersionTranslationInfo": {
                "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.VersionTranslationInfo+json",
                "Language": [{
                    "languageCode": "eng-GB"
                }]
            },
            "names": {
                "value": [{
                    "_languageCode": "eng-GB",
                    "#text": "Administrator User"
                }]
            },
            "Content": {
                "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.ContentInfo+json",
                "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/objects/14"
            }
        },
        "Fields": {
            "field": [{
                "id": 28,
                "fieldDefinitionIdentifier": "first_name",
                "languageCode": "eng-GB",
                "fieldTypeIdentifier": "ezstring",
                "fieldValue": "Administrator"
            }, {
                "id": 29,
                "fieldDefinitionIdentifier": "last_name",
                "languageCode": "eng-GB",
                "fieldTypeIdentifier": "ezstring",
                "fieldValue": "User"
            }, {
                "id": 30,
                "fieldDefinitionIdentifier": "user_account",
                "languageCode": "eng-GB",
                "fieldTypeIdentifier": "ezuser",
                "fieldValue": {
                    "hasStoredLogin": true,
                    "contentId": 14,
                    "login": "admin",
                    "email": "daniele@abd.it",
                    "passwordUpdatedAt": 1640107428,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "maxLogin": 10,
                    "plainPassword": null
                }
            }, {
                "id": 178,
                "fieldDefinitionIdentifier": "signature",
                "languageCode": "eng-GB",
                "fieldTypeIdentifier": "eztext",
                "fieldValue": "Mega boss"
            }, {
                "id": 180,
                "fieldDefinitionIdentifier": "image",
                "languageCode": "eng-GB",
                "fieldTypeIdentifier": "ezimage",
                "fieldValue": {
                    "id": "0/8/1/0/180-5-eng-GB/avatar_19.jpg",
                    "path": "/0/8/1/0/180-5-eng-GB/avatar_19.jpg",
                    "alternativeText": "",
                    "fileName": "avatar_19.jpg",
                    "fileSize": 50787,
                    "imageId": "14-180-5",
                    "uri": "/var/site/storage/images/0/8/1/0/180-5-eng-GB/avatar_19.jpg",
                    "inputUri": null,
                    "width": "480",
                    "height": "580",
                    "additionalData": [],
                    "variations": {
                        "ezplatform_admin_ui_profile_picture_user_menu": {
                            "href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/binary/images/14-180-5/variations/ezplatform_admin_ui_profile_picture_user_menu"
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/binary/images/14-180-5/variations/large"
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/binary/images/14-180-5/variations/medium"
                        },
                        "reference": {
                            "href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/binary/images/14-180-5/variations/reference"
                        },
                        "small": {
                            "href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/binary/images/14-180-5/variations/small"
                        },
                        "tiny": {
                            "href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/binary/images/14-180-5/variations/tiny"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        "Relations": {
            "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.RelationList+json",
            "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/content/objects/14/versions/5/relations",
            "Relation": []
        },
        "Thumbnail": {
            "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.Thumbnail+json",
            "resource": "/bundles/ezplatformadminui/img/ez-icons.svg#user",
            "width": null,
            "height": null,
            "mimeType": "image/svg+xml"
        }
    },
    "login": "admin",
    "email": "daniele@abd.it",
    "enabled": true,
    "UserGroups": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.UserGroupList+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/user/users/14/groups"
    },
    "Roles": {
        "_media-type": "application/vnd.ez.api.RoleAssignmentList+json",
        "_href": "/api/ezp/v2/user/users/14/roles"
    }
}
```

my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/_models';
import { EzUser } from 'src/app/_models/ezuser';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/_services';

import { UserblockService } from './userblock.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-userblock',
    templateUrl: './userblock.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./userblock.component.scss']
})
export class UserblockComponent implements OnInit {

    currentUser: EzUser;
    error = '';
    pictureUrl: string;
    user: User = {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'ippo',
      cognome: 'adad',
      tipo: {id: 1, name: 'dsad'}
    };

    constructor(public userblockService: UserblockService, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {

        this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => this.currentUser = x);
        this.pictureUrl = this.currentUser.version.fields.field[0].fieldValue.path;
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    userBlockIsVisible(): boolean{
        return this.userblockService.getVisibility();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fields')
```

in statement:

```js
this.pictureUrl = this.currentUser.version.fields.field[0].fieldValue.path;
```

which implies that `this.currentUser.version` is `undefined`

Looking at the json data shared in the question, there is no `version` property, indeed its `Version` (Uppercase **V**) and hence `this.currentUser.version` would be `undefined`.
As per json data shared in the question, the statement should be:

```js
this.pictureUrl = this.currentUser.Version.Fields.field[0].fieldValue.path;
```

Also in the json data, `this.currentUser.Version.Fields.field[0].fieldValue` value is a string as opposed to object, which might again result in an error when trying to read `fieldValue.path`.

```json
"fieldValue": "Administrator"
```

Ensuring the property names and types are in sync between model definition and json data, should resolve the issue.

Comment: I modify the model to respect the json data and now works but I have still problem with my model, please see my answer.

Comment: Hope [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types) helps.

Answer (score 1):

the field `fields` is read on `undefined` meaning your `currentUser` is undefined, indeed, you are never setting the value of `currentUser` before the constructor, I guess your code should be

```js
this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => {
   this.currentUser = x
   this.pictureUrl = this.currentUser.version.fields.field[0].fieldValue.path;
});
```

and you should check after if the picture url is set

Answer (score 0):

`this.currentUser.version` is `undefined`, caused by an extremely common mistake in asynchronous programming.

```
constructor(public userblockService: UserblockService, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => this.currentUser = x);
    this.pictureUrl = this.currentUser.version.fields.field[0].fieldValue.path;
}
```

`this.pictureUrl` depends on the assignment from the observable immediately before it, but since that is an asynchronous function, it does not wait for it to complete before continuing to assign `this.pictureUrl`.

You need to assign it within the observable, commonly I do this in the `oncomplete` [handler](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable), though it can be on the `onnext` handler as well. `oncomplete` is only invoked if there was no error.

```
constructor(public userblockService: UserblockService, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(
        user => this.currentUser = user,
        error => console.error,
        _ => this.pictureUrl = this.currentUser.version.fields.field[0].fieldValue.path
    );
}
```

You should also consider doing this in the Angular lifecycle hook [`ngOnInit()`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) and not the constructor.

Comment: i try your code but not compile

Comment: @danny36 Wait a second, I missed something in your initial question. What _is_ `this.authenticationService.currentUser`? I don't see a function invocation... Is it an HttpClient get, like your  code suggests, or is it a _singleton object_?

Comment: please look my aswer

Answer (score 0):

this is AuthenticationService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EzUser } from '../_models/ezuser';
import { EzSession } from '../_models/ezsession';
import { User } from '../_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {

    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<EzUser>;
    public currentUser: Observable<EzUser>;

    private currentSessionSubject: BehaviorSubject<EzSession>;
    public currentSession: Observable<EzSession>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {

        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<EzUser>(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ezuser')));
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

        this.currentSessionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<EzSession>(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ezsession')));
        this.currentSession = this.currentSessionSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentSessionValue(): EzSession {
      return this.currentSessionSubject.value;
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): any {
      return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

    login(username: string, pass: string): Observable<EzUser> {

      const headers = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          Accept: 'application/vnd.ez.api.Session+json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ez.api.SessionInput+json',
        })
      };

      const body = {
        SessionInput: {
          login: username,
          password: pass
        }
      };

      return this.http.post<EzSession>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/sessions`, body, headers).pipe(
        map(result => {
              // store user details and basic auth credentials in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
              // session.authdata = window.btoa(username + ':' + pass);
              // sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(session));
              result.authdata = window.btoa(username + ':' + pass);
              sessionStorage.setItem('ezsession', JSON.stringify(result));
              this.currentSessionSubject.next(result);
              return result;
        }),
        mergeMap((x) => {

          const ezsession =  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ezsession'));
          const headers2 = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': ezsession.Session['_media-type'],
              Accept: ezsession.Session.User['_media-type']
            })
          };

          return this.http.get<any>(`${ezsession.Session.User['_href']}`, headers2).pipe(map(result => {
            debugger
            sessionStorage.setItem('ezuser', JSON.stringify(result.User));
            this.currentUserSubject.next(result);
            return result.User;
          }));
        })
      );
    }

    logout(): Observable<any[]> {
      const ezsession =  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ezsession'));
      const headers = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          Cookie: ezsession.Session.name + '=' + ezsession.Session.identifier,
          'X-CSRF-Token': ezsession.Session.csrfToken
        })
      };

      return this.http.delete<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/sessions/${ezsession.Session.identifier}`, headers).pipe(
        map(result => {
          sessionStorage.removeItem('ezsession');
          sessionStorage.removeItem('ezuser');
          this.currentSessionSubject.next(null);
          this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
          return result;
        })
      );
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How can I access to "fieldValue" if is a object or string?

if I try to access:

**this.pictureUrl = this.currentUser.Version.Fields.field[4].fieldValue.id;**

I get a compilation error:

**Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string | FieldValueClass'.**

```
export interface Field {
  id: number;
  fieldDefinitionIdentifier: string;
  languageCode: string;
  fieldTypeIdentifier: string;
  fieldValue: FieldValueClass | string;
}
```